# Finding href link which contains text

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml like the following.

```
<div id="test">    
    <div id="mw-normal-catlinks" class="mw-normal-catlinks">
        <a href="/wiki/Help:Category" title="Help:Category">Categories</a>:
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/wiki/Category:1961_births" title="Category:1961 births">1961 births</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/wiki/Category:Gadjah_Mada_University_alumni" title="Category:Gadjah Mada University alumni">Gadjah Mada University alumni</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="mw-hidden-catlinks" class="mw-hidden-catlinks mw-hidden-cats-hidden">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/wiki/Category:Pages_using_web_citations_with_no_URL" title="Category:Pages using web citations with no URL">Pages using web citations with no URL</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/wiki/Category:CS1_Indonesian-language_sources_(id)" title="Category:CS1 Indonesian-language sources (id)">CS1 Indonesian-language sources (id)</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract the categories "1961 births", "Gadjah Mada University alumni" from [div id="mw-normal-catlinks"].

If I use the following xpath, I get what I want but the xpath also extracts "Pages using web citations with no URL", and "CS1 Indonesian-language sources (id)" from the [div id="mw-hidden-catlinks"].

```
//a[contains(@href,"/wiki/Category")]
```

Using the xpath below I get no result.

```
//DIV[@id="mw-normal-catlinks"]/a[contains(@href,"/wiki/Category")]
```

Anyone can help me with the correct xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shall do: `.//div[@id="mw-normal-catlinks"]/ul//a`. It returns both the `a` tags `1961 births`, `Gadjah Mada University alumni` from `div[@id="mw-normal-catlinks"]`.